# Illustrator CC shortcut: Select next layer in layer palette

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts, osx

I'm looking for a simple Illustrator **shortcut to select the next/previous layer** in the layer's panel for OSX.
According to [this post](https://forums.creativecow.net/archivethread/58/748112), <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> should cycle through the layers, but this seems to no longer work in Illustrator CC.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: Thanks @Luciano, I had already taken a look at that page before but it does not contain any reference to a shortcut like that. Unless you're seeing something that I'm not?

Comment: that shortcut is for photoshop not illustrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage there is no shortcut to accomplish this.